# Algolia InstantSearch Hook - search for an array of objectIDs

Tags: algolia, instantsearch

we're using Algolia's InstantSearch React hook

I figured I could do something like the following

```
<InstantSearch 
    indexName={indexName} 
    searchClient={algoliaClient}
    searchState={{
       query: [
          "objectID:80066451052",
           "objectID:50090402178"]
    }}>
      <Configure clickAnalytics />
      {children}
 </InstantSearch>
```

But it turns out that the InstantSearch hook does not support searchState the way the older InstantSearch component does.

So can anyone help me turn the query above into one that will work with the InstantSearch hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version you're using and how your index is configured.

However, the query can be passed directly to the Configure component like any other search parameter you can found here

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/search-api-parameters/

So you can write this

```
<InstantSearch 
indexName={indexName} 
searchClient={algoliaClient}
>
  <Configure query={myQuery} clickAnalytics/>
  {children}
</InstantSearch>
```

Comment: I believe this should work, I tried that earlier also so maybe there is another problem going on -  the child node respresented by {children} is the following: 

const SearchProductsResults = (props) => {
        console.log("local component");
        console.log(props);
        const { hits } = useHits(props);

        return null;
    }
but my SearchProductsResults component only gets an empty object as the props.

Comment: The data is coming back from the query, can see that in the network panel. Just isn't being passed to the child node props - maybe I should make another question.

Comment: Yes, it is a different problem. If this response solves your problem with the query, validate it, close the topic and make another question. I'll be glad to check.